# jQuery, popups & clearing and setting interval

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drop-down-menu, setinterval

Using jQuery 1.9.1 and have a `setInterval` to refresh the page every X seconds.  I have code in the page to use the `jQuery-ui Dialog` box, but need to change it to function with a popup window instead.  The issue is that the page itself will only be a specific size on the screen & a `dialog` can only be positioned within the window itself.  Since the content will look similar between the page & the popup/dialog, I need the popup to be able to display in the center of the screen, as opposed to the positioning available within the `jquery-ui dialog`.

I retrieve a row count from a SQL table, if count > 0 then display the popup.  If row count = 0 then no popup.  If the row count > 0, I clear the interval & wait for some action to occur in the popup.  Once it occurs, I need to close the window & re-start the interval from the main page.

Because the action on the popup can take longer than the interval I have defined I have to keep track of when the interval was stopped. Before the interval gets restarted, I need to call the SQL stored procedure with the time it stopped in order to retrieve what is new since then & then re-start the interval.  The check for a row count > 0 will be part of the re-started interval.

As an example - my initial page will be 1000px wide by 300px high and it will occupy the bottom third of the screen.  The popup would be the same size, but would need to occupy the center of the screen.

Questions -

1. Can the `jQuery-ui Dialog` be positioned anywhere other than inside the window it is already in?  Since what I have (using this) works & stops & starts the Interval, I'd prefer to do this if it is just a matter of positioning the dialog.
2. If it can't be done using the `jQuery-ui Dialog` - how can you re-start an interval that was cleared before the popup was called?  What I need to do is to call the function in the main page from within the popup before it closes.

As it is now, I am catching a change event in a dropdown box within that dialog, calling the function and only re-starting the interval once the rowcount = 0, but all of this is from within the same page & using the `jQuery-ui Dialog`.

I'd appreciate any thoughts or suggestions as to how best to accomplish this.

**EDIT**

The main "page" will be inside a frame & will occupy the bottom third of the entire web page.  The dialog, unless I'm not setting it up correctly will only occupy that same space on the screen, while a popup would not.

Comment: Why don't you use ajax, so you won't have to refresh anything, while also avoiding setInterval?

Comment: I'm confused...if you're reloading the page, why would you need `setInterval` as opposed to `setTimeout`? The interval will only ever run once before the page gets reloaded. And I'm not sure what you mean in question #1. You want a dialog to be positioned outside of the window? Like outside of the browser? I would really hope that's not possible. As for your second question, to restart an interval that has been cleared, you just call `setInterval`, same as you did the first time. As @Cristy suggested, I'm betting that AJAX would be the way to go.

Comment: I am using AJAX.  The interval calls a function that does a `GET` on the SQL table, using a date-time (and other info) as input - such as id=10,dt='2013-07-08 13:25:01.223',pri=X and the next time the interval occurs, the id & pri are the same but the time has changed.  Each page is calling the same stored procedure, but the popup is looking at pri=Z instead. Pri=X won't stop the interval, but Pri=Z in the popup will.